# Get normal google image search results in google custom search API

Tags: android, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I want my app to give sample images based on what the user typed.
I created a custom search engine, already ticked "search entire web but emphasise...", and ticked "Image Search".
Created an html GET request as per Google's instructions.

```
 String start = "start=0";

    // looking for
    String strNoSpaces = toSearchIn.replace(" ", "+");

    String url2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?"

            + "key=" + keyBrowser
            + "&cx=" + cx
            + "&q=" + strNoSpaces

            + start

            + "&searchtype=image"

            + "&alt=json";


    return url2;
```

and it all works well, I retrieve the image URLs and inflate the grid view. 
The problem is the quality of results. It is nowhere near the relevance of what you see on the main google.com search results, and it was kind of my goal. The results that I am getting are rather disappointing and make the whole feature not worth it.

For comparison

[my "party"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge8j4.png) results

[Normal search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YXfH.png) results

Can this be changed with some parameters? I already tried most of them without much difference